Delete a delta table partition based on the creation/modification date of the partition folder
As I understand, there is a vaccum command in delta to remove the old versions from delta table.
My Usecase:
However, I would like to remove the partition completely based on the modification date of the partition.
For example:
date=2024-11-22 is my partition name and the modification date of it is 2024-11-30, I want to remove the partition whose modification date are older than 30 days
How to perform this efficiently with the delta features and without losing the durability?

did you try a simple delete ?

I have tried simple delete and it creates new version in deltalog, but the .parquet file was still present.

You're mixing up two different things here:

Cleaning up files that no longer belong to the Delta table (this is what VACUUM does).
Deleting data that still exists in the table but is considered outdated.

In your case, there's no built-in way to remove partitions based on the modification date directly. A good workaround would be to add a new column to your table to track the "update timestamp" (basically your modification date).
Once you have that, you can simply run a DELETE query like this:
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE update_date < '2024-11-30';

Delta Lake supports standard DML commands like DELETE, so this works natively without any additional setup.
If you can't add a new column, you'll need to extract some other information to identify the rows you want to remove. If the partition date itself is sufficient, you can use it and perform a simple DELETE.

Read up on time travel and vacuuming.
DELETE command will delete the data from current/latest version of the table (say v10) and create a new version (say v11), which becomes the current/latest version. By default you interact with a table (e.g. SELECT * from table) you're interacting with v11. You can interact with an older version of the table if you want as well, as long as that version exists. E.g. SELECT * from table VERSION AS OF v8
Note the versions are actually numbers (8, 10, 11) not text (v8, v10, v11).
VACUUM deletes older "versions" (snapshots) of the table, e.g. v10. After you vacuum, you lose the ability to time travel to the deleted versions of the table.

Is there a way to vaccum only to delete the references which are marked for deletion, my end goal is to remove the underlying parquet file and last 7 versions of time travel to be maintained

Read through the links posted until you understand them fully and it should answer your question. Which is already answered in my and Steven's post above.

Thanks for the guidance
